# Implement SSO in windows application/vsto plugins

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, single-sign-on, vsto, azure-active-directory

I have a requirement to implement SSO for desktop applications created using WPF and office plugins developed using VSTO. I have some basic knowledge about SSO that how it works for websites (based on redirection).
I did some research and found that there is no way we can access the WebBrowser control in WPF to get the access token. I need to use the access token to call the rest services created in java and hosted on some URL.

Is there any way to get access token using windows applications.

Also, as per my understanding only Web-Addins support SSO with Azure AD v2.0. Can you guide me to some good links to achieve it? Please let me know if my question makes sense or some additional information is required.
*All clients do not use Azure AD solution.

Comment: There is a sample for WPF so I think it works: https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget :)

Comment: Although @juunas is right about samples, StackOverflow is not the place to ask such generic questions. Do your homework first before seeking for help. I vote to close this question, because:
Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it!